# undefined method `lastname' for nil:NilClass rails - Avatar issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

OK, not sure what I did.. but it was working before and now it stopped. 
I'm currently trying to add initials as the avatar to users' navbar, following [this step by step guide](https://codediode.io/lessons/198632-default-avatars-with-username-initials)

It all makes sense and I did what was required, but for some reason I'm now getting the error of undefined method..  [image]

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong to be honest...Obviosly, users have attribute of firstname and lastname.. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**UsersHelper**

```
module UsersHelper
    def show_avatar(user)
        render partial: 'users/avatar'
    end

end
```

**Avatar partial under users/_avatar**

```
<div class=“avatar-circle-sm”>
    <span class="initials">
        <%= @user.lastname[0..1].upcase %>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Page navbar shared/_navbar**

```
    <div>      
      <%= show_avatar(@user) %>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're not setting the variable `@user` which is why it's nil which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: Can I just ask you where should I set up the variable? Sorry, I'm really new tu rails.. thanks

Comment: Probably in the `home` action of your `pages_controller` since that's where the error is being thrown (as stated in the image you posted).

Comment: You are right. It actually works on the user page (that's why I thought it was working before, now it doesn't).. I tweaked the show of the page controller, but I'm still getting the error.   'def home @user = User.find(params[:id])  end' Should I do it something different? The error says "Couldn't find User with 'id'="

Comment: ...check your params. I guarantee you there's no `:id` in there. Are you using Devise or some similar? Saving a user to cookies or session?

Comment: I'm using device, yes. You were right, I don't have params defined in page_controller( following a tutorial, but not for this bit here).. I tweaked def home to @user = current_user.id and now I'm back to the previous issue of undefined method lastname :( It is so frustrating!!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155670/discussion-between-jvillian-and-lily).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in chat, since you're using Devise, you can use `current_user` instead of setting a new @user variable.